# Stereo NvAPI init delayed

Tags: directx-9, stereo-3d, nvapi

I have directx9 application and a problem with nVidia's stereo api (automatic mode). Commands like `NvAPI_Stereo_Activate()` start working ONLY after first `present()` on directx device. All nvapi initialization was done well (got everywhere `NvAPI_OK`).

Comment: What about a workaround with an "warmup" `present()`?

Comment: Yes, that is the option, but making NvApi work right - better